# Configuring jquery plugin with webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, webpack, bootstrap-multiselect

Im trying to configure jquery plugin [multiselect](http://loudev.com/#usage) to work with webpack.

But i'm getting

```
$(...).multiSelect is not a function
```

I have included it in alias

```
alias: {
            'multiSelect': Path.join(__dirname, '../public/plugins/jquery-multi-select/js/jquery.multi-select.js')
          }
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var Path = require('path')
var ProvidePlugin = require('webpack/lib/ProvidePlugin')

module.exports = {
    module: {
        loaders: [
                { test: /bootstrap\/js\//, loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery' }
            ]
    },
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        'multiSelect': Path.join(__dirname, '../public/plugins/jquery-multi-select/js/jquery.multi-select.js')
      }
    },
    entry: Path.join(__dirname, '../public/Entry.js'),
    output: {
        path: Path.join(__dirname, '../public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new ProvidePlugin({
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            $: 'jquery',
            jquery: 'jquery'
        })
    ],
}
```

**Entry.js**

```
var multiSelect = require('multiSelect')
$('#my-select').multiSelect() // $(...).multiSelect is not a function
```

Answer (score 2):

Multiselect plugin uses IIFE:

```
!function ($) {
   ...
}(window.jQuery);
```

So you can try to change your `Entry.js` file like this:

```
window.jQuery = jquery;
var multiSelect = require('multiSelect');
$('#my-select').multiSelect();
```

or you can change your `webpack.config.js`:

```
new ProvidePlugin({
  jQuery: 'jquery',
  $: 'jquery',
  jquery: 'jquery',
  'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
})
```

Comment: in my  case it was: `plugins[new webpack.ProvidePlugin(...)]`